# Can I apply for a future student visa while I have a current valid one?

Tags: visa, student-visa, poland

I am a Ukranian student in Poland. I have a national visa from 18.11.2018 to 17.11.2019. Can I apply for a Polish visa from 18.11.2019 to 17.11.2020 on 05.08.2019?

Comment: For clarity, are you asking about another visa for Poland, or for a different country? The question title implies you’re seeking another student visa but that’s not clear in your question either

Comment: I am asking for another visa to Poland(the same type of visa). My question is can i apply for visa before the ending of the old one(ends on 17.11.2019), i apply for visa tommorow and want to ask for visa from 18.11.2019 to 17.11.2020.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but it would make sense for any government to accept student visa applications well in advance of the study dates. The school will often require that tuition be paid well in advance, and a prudent student wouldn't pay the tuition until the visa was obtained. Also, the student would want to know ahead of time if the visa was denied, so the student would have time to apply to schools in other countries or enter the work force.